# Comparando data e hora em campos diferente

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela que contem os seguintes campos nome do tipo `(nvarchar)`, Data do tipo `(Date)` e hora do  tipo `(Time)`.

Preciso fazer a comparação por período exemplo: `08-02-2019 e 18:30:10 até 30-05-2019 e 07:45:11`

Como faço isso na consulta em sql server

Estava tentando dessa forma mas sei que não funciona:

```
SELECT        pessoa.nome, acesso.data, acesso.hora
FROM            acesso 
INNER JOIN pessoa ON acesso.id_pessoa = pessoa.id
WHERE        (acesso.data >= @data1) AND (acesso.data <= @data2) and   (acesso.hora >= @horaInicio and acesso.hora <= @horafim)
```

Comment: Combine seus campos data e hora em um campo do tipo datetime e faça uma única verificação se está no intervalo.

Comment: Não posso mudar a estrutura do banco, por que é de terceiro e já existe vários dados.

Comment: Eu não falei em mudar a estrutura do banco e sim combinar os campos em seu select para fazer a comparação. Não uso nem o Microsoft SQL Server e nem o SQLite para exemplificar como fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT P.nome, A.data, A.hora
  from acesso as A
       inner join Pessoa as P on A.id_pessoa = P.id
  where A.data between @data1 and @data2
        and 1 = (case when A.data = @data1 
                           then case when A.hora >= @horaInicio then 1 else 0 end
                      else 1 end)
        and 1 = (case when A.data = @data2 
                           then case when A.hora <= @horafim then 1 else 0 end
                      else 1 end);
```

Answer (score 2):

No **SQLServer 2008 R2**
uma possibilidade seria a seguinte:

```
SELECT
  pessoa.nome,
  acesso.data,
  acesso.hora     
FROM acesso
INNER JOIN pessoa ON acesso.id_pessoa = pessoa.id
WHERE CAST(acesso_data AS datetime) + CAST(acesso_hora AS time) BETWEEN 
CAST(@data1 AS datetime) + CAST(@horaInicio AS time) AND CAST(@data2 AS datetime) + CAST(@horaFim AS time)
```

Comment: Mas a pergunta é sobre `sqlite` e não `SQL Server`

Comment: @Sorack, blza!! Então acho que o mba se enganou quando informou as tags no corpo da pergunta, ele descreve: ***Como faço isso na consulta em sql server***

Comment: Assim também funciona @Oliveira, mas como estou trabalhando com varias versões do sql server e o `CAST `  não esta disponível no 2005 e 2008, optei pela aquela forma. Parabéns e Obrigado.

Comment: @blza, pode-ser que contribua com outros Dev's com essa versão do SQLServer.

Comment: Editei a pergunta tirando a tag do sqlite para não confundir mas ninguém. Obrigado.

Comment: @Oliveira com certeza vai contribuir sim. Abraços